# Executing initialization code before java_import in JRuby?

Tags: ruby, initialization, jruby

Does java_import always execute before initialize in JRuby?

I need the following code to execute

```
def initialize vlc_path
    @vlc_path = vlc_path || get_vlc_path
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName,"/Applications/VLC .app/Contents/MacOS/lib")
end
```

before I can use:

```
java_import 'uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc'
```

The java_import always executes first and fails. How to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods get called when they get … well … called. If you call `initialize` before you call `java_import` it will execute first, if you call it after `java_import` it will execute after `java_import`.

If you want to call `initialize` before you call `java_import`, you need to call `initialize` before you call `java_import`.